# Removing unnecessary tags with str_replace

Tags: php, string, replace

Let’s say I have some `$content` like this

```
<div class="span2">
    <p><br />
        Here goes some other content …<br />
        More content …
    <br /></p>
</div>
```

from which I’d like to remove only the `<br />` tags after the opening `<p>` tag and before the closing `<p>`tag.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn’t work …

```
preg_replace('/<div[^>]><p><br />(.+)<br /><\/p><\/div>/i', '$1', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/<div[^>]*><p><br\s\/>(.+)<br\s/><\/p><\/div>/i', '$1', $content);
```

I am not a php-programmer, but maybe this regexp-part is now correct.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error message: `preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '>'`

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you wouldn't use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php? You could specify to leave `<p>` and `<div>` tags alone. Only works if your case is always this simple though. If you want to leave any `<br />` in the middle alone, then this probably isn't ideal.

Comment: There could be other <br /> in the content section, so not all should be stripped out. I updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function strpbrp($content){
  if(preg_match('/<div[^>]*>/', $content, $m)){
    return "$m[0]<p>".preg_replace('/(^<div[^>]*>\s*<p>\s*<br\s*\/>)|(<br\s*\/>\s*<\/p>\s*<\/div>$)/', '', $content).'</p></div>';
  }
  else{
    return $content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t …